# nsupdate: What does the error NOTIMP mean?

Tags: dns, updates

I tried to add a dns entry using nsupdate:

```
printf 'update add myhost.mydomain.com 86400 A 172.16.1.1\nsend\n' | nsupdate
```

I'm getting the error:

```
 update failed: NOTIMP
```

what does it mean?

Answer (score 7):

It means that the nameserver which received the request does **not imp**lement DNS "UPDATE" (RFC 2136) requests, that is, it doesn't support dynamic updates.

But make sure you're sending the update to the correct server; try using the `server …` command before anything else.

Answer (score 7):

I am getting the same error on a simple query

```
dig any eoaclk.com @1.1.1.1

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.5 <<>> any eoaclk.com @1.1.1.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: **NOTIMP**, id: 19761
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
```

It appears the answer is still "not implemented", and I can verify that with just the fact that I **can** get a response from a reduced query to the same server. Apparently this server doesn't support the "ANY" option.

```
$ dig eoaclk.com @1.1.1.1

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.5 <<>> eoaclk.com @1.1.1.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 2395
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;eoaclk.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
eoaclk.com.             60      IN      A       35.167.132.154
eoaclk.com.             60      IN      A       52.40.97.221
eoaclk.com.             60      IN      A       54.213.184.87

;; Query time: 129 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Apr 23 10:59:21 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 76
```